How do I import a gnupg public key using only Ansible?
I am using Ansible role DebOps wpcli: https://docs.debops.org/en/stable-3.1/ansible/roles/wpcli/index.html
The error is:
TASK [debops.debops.wpcli : Verify and install wp-cli binary] ******************
fatal: [webserver]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd: set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit && gpg --batch --decrypt --output /usr/local/src/wpcli/wp-cli-2.5.0.phar /usr/local/src/wpcli/wp-cli-2.5.0.phar.gpg && ( install --mode 755 --owner root --group root /usr/local/src/wpcli/wp-cli-2.5.0.phar /usr/local/bin/wp && install --mode 644 --owner root --group root /usr/local/src/wpcli/wp-cli-2.5.0.completion.bash /etc/bash_completion.d/wp-completion ) || ( rm -f /usr/local/src/wpcli/wp-cli-2.5.0.phar && exit 2 )
  delta: '0:00:00.092231'
  end: '2024-09-05 06:45:25.499750'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 2
  start: '2024-09-05 06:45:25.407519'
  stderr: |-
    gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
    gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
    gpg: Signature made Wed May 19 15:24:41 2021 UTC
    gpg:                using RSA key 63AF7AA15067C05616FDDD88A3A2E8F226F0BC06
    gpg:                issuer "releases@wp-cli.org"
    gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

I already know how to fix this using plain Bash shell: Can't check signature: public key not found.
I don't want to fix it with shell commands, but I need to achieve it using Ansible.
My question is: how do I fix this error using Ansible or even better with an existing DebOps role?
Edit based on first answer:
I should clarify that this is not in the context of apt-get, there is no APT keyring involved at all. The wpcli role is distribution neutral and works on Debian, Redhat, Suse, Arch, and any other distro that supports Ansible.

By using debops.keyring role.
Have this in meta/main.yml:
---
dependencies:
  - role: debops.debops.keyring
    keyring__dependent_gpg_keys:
      - id: 63AF7AA15067C05616FDDD88A3A2E8F226F0BC06
  - role: debops.debops.wpcli


The keyring role will first install the key 63AF7AA15067C05616FDDD88A3A2E8F226F0BC06 into root's gnupg keyring, and then the wpcli role will find the key there.

By using apt_key module.
- name: Add an apt key by id from a keyserver
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    keyserver: keyserver.ubuntu.com
    id: 63AF7AA15067C05616FDDD88A3A2E8F226F0BC06

or you can download it and then use it in you apt:
- name: apt key
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x63af7aa15067c05616fddd88a3a2e8f226f0bc06
    dest: /etc/apt/keyrings/myrepo.asc

- name: somerepo | apt source
  ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
    repo: "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/myrepo.asc] https://someexample.com/linux/ubuntu {{ ansible_distribution_release }} stable"
    state: present


Won't that add the key to just the apt keyring used only by apt-get? Not to the main gnupg keyring.
